# Rails fixtures :has_many and :belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

How do I create sample data in my .yml for has_many and belongs_to variables.

This is a sample adding these files into a simple rails new lab command in the terminal. I don't really know how to explain this in english. But I hope my code shows enough detail to get the point across.

man.rb

```
class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :items
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :man
end
```

men.yml

```
one:
  name: ManOne
  #items: one, two

two:
  name: ManTwo
  #items: one, two
```

items.yml

```
one:
  name: ItemOne

two:
  name: ItemTwo
```

man_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ManTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_man
    Man.all.each do |man|
      puts man.name.to_s + ": " + man.items.to_s
    end
    assert true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look to fixtures [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html), you can do somehting like:

men.yml

```
man_one:
  name: ManOne

man_two:
  name: ManTwo
```

items.yml

```
item_one:
  name: ItemOne
  man: man_one

item_two:
  name: ItemTwo
  man: man_one

item_three:
  name: ItemThree
  man: man_two
```

**Update**

It seems you don't have the `man_id` in the table `column`. You should create a migration to do so:

```
rails g migration AddManIdToItem man_id:integer
```

and run the migration: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: I added in the changes you did.

Then I did

    puts men(:man_one).items

in the man_test.rb

I got an error

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table items has no column named man_id: INSERT INTO "items" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at", "id", "man_id") VALUES ('ItemOne', '2014-03-27 23:09:59', '2014-03-27 23:09:59', 494534085, 82093985)

Comment: You don't have the man_id column in item. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about fixtures. You do it like this:

```
#men.yml
first_man:
  name: 'One'

#items.yml
first_item:
  name: 'First item'
  man: first_man
```